# how to pass parameters from ssrs to wcf service

Tags: sql-server, wcf, reporting-services

we have to pass parameters of datetime ,string, int types to the wcf service. with this the exception thrown is

"Error - SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM while passing parameters from ssrs"

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the date is not within a range. The error is an sql error.

So, probably you are sending a datetime parameter that has not been given a value. It then defaults to year 0. When you try to insert this date into an sql table you get a SQL error.

The solution would therefore to initialize the datetime parameter to a value in the above range.